# May two vectors be non-parallel and have a dot product equal to one?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that if two vectors are parallel, the dot product is equal to the multiplication of their magnitudes. If their magnitudes are normalized, then this is equal to one. However, is it possible that two vectors (whose vectors need not be normalized) are nonparallel and their dot product is equal to one?

Comment: Nope.   Basic equation.

Comment: How about two vectors that have an angle between them of 60 degrees and each of whose magnitudes are $\sqrt{2}.$ Then, $1 = cos60\sqrt{2}^2 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2.$

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud If two *normalized* (magnitude 1) vectors have dot product 1, then they are equal. If their magnitudes are not constrained to be 1, then there are many counterexamples, such as the one in your comment.

Comment: Thanks bungo! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the colored vectors dotted into the normalized black (horizontal) vector gives a dot product of 1.

[image]

Comment: Hi, David! I believe you misread the question. It is not an assumption of mine that the magnitudes are one!

Comment: Please rewrite the question to clarify that the vectors need *not* be normalized, which BOTH answerers understood to be the case.

Comment: Done! Thanks, David!